# Как скачать релиз docker image Elasticsearch двухлетней давности?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

Нужен Elasticsearch в контейнере определенной версии. Как скачать законно? На hub.docker.com только за 2023 год нахожу. На сайте Elastic описание только 8 версии, поэтому даже не знаю точно, какая версия нужна.

Comment: а конкретный номер версии вы знаете? ну и на hub docker есть старые версии https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/tags?page=2, например 7.16.3 был загружен два года назад

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Гуглим "elasticsearch versions", вторая [ссылка](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/releases) - список релизов на гитхабе. Немного походим по страницам, выясняем, что Oct 14, 2021 состоялся релиз `Elasticsearch 7.15.1`.

Дальше гуглим ещё, и вот:

```
docker pull bitnami/elasticsearch:7.15.1
```

Или вот:

```
docker pull elastic/elasticsearch:7.15.1
```

Можно искать по тегам на хабе в конкретном репозитории:
https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/elasticsearch/tags?page=1&name=7.15.1